# WinForm User Control functionality in Android

Tags: android, custom-controls, xamarin

I am new to android development and am working on my first android app. I've come across a scenario where I need to dynamically add 2 `textboxes` and a `checkbox` to a list for each object in a list. If I was using winforms I would use a custom user control and handle the `checkedChanged` event inside the custom control.

I've googled around and only been able to find tutorials on how to build your own controls from the ground up. While that is helpful, all I want to do is combine 3 default controls into a single custom control and I am having no luck at all in finding a tutorial that goes through how to do this.

Does anyone know if what I am describing is possible, and if it is, is there a good reference out there that shows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance) tutorial(using Xamarin) laid out how to accomplish what I needed.